# Specialization of member class nested in a non-specialized class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, specialization

```
template <typename T>
struct A
   {
   template <typename U>
   struct B;

   template <>
   struct B<int> {static const int tag = 1;};  // Works fine in VS2010
   };
```

How can I specialize B the same way, but outside of A.  I tried this with no success :

```
template <typename T> template <>
struct A<T>::B<int> {static const int tag = 1;};
```

I get:

`error C3212: 'A<T>::B<int>' : an explicit specialization of a template member must be a member of an explicit specialization`

It does not make sense since I can do exactly that by defining it inside the class

VS2010 problem?  Wrong syntax?

Thanks

---

PS: This one (which should be wrong anyway, crashes VS2010):

```
template <> template <typename T>
struct A<T>::B<int> {static const int tag = 1;};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the C++ spec, §14.17.3.18:

> In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain unspecialzed, **except that the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well**. [...]

(my emphasis)

This suggests that you can't specialize a template class nested inside another template class unless the outer template class is specialized as well.  So it looks like VS2010 has this behavior wrong and g++ has it right.

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea why the exception?  Conceptually it would seem acceptable to allow it.

Comment: @Frigg- If I had to guess, it would be to prevent ambiguities between having an outer specialization with an inner template and an outer template with an inner specialization, but I have absolutely no idea.  I didn't know this was illegal until you posted the question. :-)

Comment: To my limited mind, this doesn't seem very ambiguous.  I have a hard time imagining them adding an exception just for that.  Any exception begets problems, there is more ambiguities with them than without them (as in this case if you ask me).  :(

Answer (score 1):

It just doesn't work that way.:-(

You cannot specialize a function inside the class declaration, even though msvc accepts this with its default settings.

You also cannot specialize a member function without also specializing the enclosing class. Most compilers avred on this (as does the language standard).